# How to specify type hint for <class 'type'>

Tags: python, mypy

I have a function which takes a value such as `np.uint8`. For example:

```
import numpy as np

def my_func(data_type):
    # do stuff

# call
my_func(np.uint8)
```

What should the type hit for `data_type` be?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type, https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html

Comment: `def my_func(data_type: type)`?

Answer (score 0):

*Edited now that I understand the question.*

I think this is what you want :
https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type

The function takes the "Type" of any of the types in the "Union".

```
import numpy as np
from typing import Union, Type

def my_func(data_type: Type[Union[np.uint8, np.uint16, ..., int64]]):
    # do stuff
    pass
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my question

Comment: Ah yeah ok, I didn't get it. You want the input to the function to take the type np.uint8 rather than a value of type np.uint8?